# Android event for all interface orientation changes?

Tags: android, orientation

Does the Android API expose an event/callback/notification that is triggered when the interface orientation is changed?

Specifically when the return value of: `Activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()` (or `getRotation`) would change?

I would use `Activity.onConfigurationChanged` or `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceChanged`, but these do not fire when the orientation is directly rotated 180 degrees (eg: from landscape-left directly to landscape-right).

Clearly Android itself is taking some action when the device is flipped like this - it flips the display to match. So what I need is some notification of when it does this.

Comment: Andrew Russell, I know this is an "ancient" question, but did you ever find a solution? I have the exact same question (I need to do some pre-layout adjustments when the orientation flips, to account for the camera notch and soft system buttons, but attach/detach doesn't run when flipping landscape-to-landscape), but if I post, it's likely to be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Activity is restarted when the orientation is changed (meaning that the onDestroy() is triggered). Maybe this helps a bit...

Comment: No it doesn't. Two reasons: firstly this is the same mechanism as `onConfigurationChanged` - I am simply requesting to receive the event, rather than an Activity restart. And secondly it suffers from the same issue: it does not happen when the orientation is directly flipped 180 degrees.

Comment: `onDestroy` doesn't trigger when you flip the device 180 degrees?

Comment: Nope - just tested it myself. Moreover, the `Configuration.orientation` doesn't even differentiate between the two different landscape (or portrait) directions.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this interface [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)

Comment: This fires at a fixed rate and returns the sensor data in degrees. It's not directly useful for tracking the *interface* orientation.

Comment: uh no it doesn't, it might fire multiple time (For me it fires anywhere from 0 to 10 times when it rotated) when the device is rotated but then it settles down (events fired is zero). It gives you the orientation from 0 - 360 degrees when the device is rotated.

Comment: Correct - I tested it. It does fire at a fixed rate (as per the documentation) but it will skip firing if the value returned would be the same as the last time it fires. The returned value is not usable without a way to correlate it to the interface orientation. At a stretch it could be used to poll `getRotation` - although it would have to be a fluke of the implementation if it fires *during* the display flip (does it?), or even serially with it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by interface orientation? I think it will be fired and later on the activity will destroyed and recreated to handle the display flip..

Comment: By interface orientation I mean the four possible directions for the device to display its interface, as returned by `Display.getRotation` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation())). The activity restart won't help - it's the same mechanism as `onConfigurationChanged` and has the same flaw - see my replies to to SYLARRR's answer ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329823/android-event-for-all-interface-orientation-changes/7330716#7330716)).

Comment: My device changes the interface orientation only twice at 0 and 90 degrees for other orientation it doesn't change the interface, say for example at 360 deg the interface is still in 0 degrees it's upside down same with 270 degrees